# How do you do "public betas" on iPad?

Tags: ipad

A friend of mine is interested in developing an iPad application, and he's heard that "most iPad apps don't offer public beta versions".

Is it true? What mechanisms can he use to distribute a private or public beta version of his app?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute them in a couple different ways:

A) distribute the source code.  This will allow other developers who have an apple developer account to compile and install the app onto their iPad.
B) Release a version 1.0 on the app store and mention that it is still very rough/may have some bugs, and to please provide feedback (obviously only works for public betas)
C) Create a repository for installation of the app via something like Cydia on jailbroken devices.  This will allow anyone with a jailbroken device to try your app without the need to give them the source code.  Obviously this will allow you to do certain things that you wouldn't be allowed to do normally, so you'll have to make sure you don't do any of those things inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

All of this answer is re: Private beta - which is mentioned in your verbiage but not your title.

There used to be a website called ibetatest.com that did iOS beta testing (I have no affiliation with them, only remember seeing their offering, which looked interesting).

Additionally, if he wants to do it himself, he'll have to find users of the iPad who are willing to beta test for him.  In the distribution instructions on the apple developers site, it will tell you how to make ad-hoc distributions available which he can then disseminate to his beta testers.

This is the short answer, it's quite involved, but once you've gotten to that point, it's something he will be intimately involved with.